# loop not working?

Tags: c++

After the call for Back to Main Menu, it returns to the mainMenu but when option or command is typed, the option is not accepted or the loop not working. Wonder where is the mistake? Is it extra call should be added or?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char mainMenu(void);
int factorial(int n);
unsigned long long combination(long nK, long nR);

int main(){
char option;
int shape,function,i,j,k,t,n;
long nK, nR;
unsigned long long COM;

while((option=mainMenu())!='0')
{
    switch(option)
    {
        case '1'://Program 1: 
            cout<< "*Drawing a shape\n"
                << "(1-Rectangle, 2-Triangle, 3-Inverted Triangle, 4-Letter 'H', 0-Back to Main Menu)\n";
            do
            {
                cout<< "Choose shape >> ";
                cin>> shape;
                cout<< endl;

                switch(shape)
                {
                    case 1: break;
                    case 2: break;
                    case 3: break;
                    case 4: break;
                    case 0:
                        //Back to Main Menu
                        cout<< "Back to main menu\n"
                            << endl;
                        return mainMenu();     //After here, it does back to Main Menu but command or option is not working 
                    }
            }while(shape!=0);

        case '2': //Program 2
            cout<< "*Choose function of calculator\n"
                << "(1-Factorial, 2-Combination, 0-Back to main menu)\n";
            do
            {
                cout<< "Choose function >> ";
                cin>> function;
                cout<< endl;

                switch(function)
                {
                    case 1: break;
                    case 2: break;
                    case 0:
                        cout<< "Back to main menu\n"
                            << endl;
                        return mainMenu();
                }
            }while(function!=0);
        case '0':
            cout<< "Program is terminating\n"
                << endl;
            return 0;
        default:
            cout<< "Wrong input. Please choose one of the above options.\n"
                << endl;
            return mainMenu();
    }
}
}

char mainMenu(void){
char option;
cout<< "##############################\n"
    << "Main Menu\n"
    << "Enter your command!\n"
    << "##############################\n"
    << endl
    << "1. Program1\n"
    << "2. Program2\n"
    << "0. Exit\n"
    << endl
    << "Command >> ";
cin>> option;
cout<< endl;
return option;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of the programming language called "void", could you perhaps retag this question with the right language?

Comment: Please actually show us the code that is causing this error, and the line that the error occurs on. The code as shown is missing `#include` statements, and variable declarations.

Comment: maybe if you tell us what the error is, what you expect to happen, and what actually happened someone might able to help, but otherwise you are just going to down voted and the question will be closed.

Comment: Im sorry for incomplete code is posted. As you can see, in every problem, there is a 'Back to Main Menu' call which is case 0. When the code compiled, it comes out with the main menu and ends with -------Command >> (but also)Choose function>>'. So i attempted to use return mainMenu() for the first question, but the error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, but your code is missing 2 important things. First, you need `break` statements at the end of each `case` block, otherwise the program flow will continue on to the next `case` statement.

Second, the inner menu doesn't ever escape the inner `while(1)` loop. This is a possible case for a `goto` use, although in practice it would better to refactor the code to split the top menu and inner menu into two functions, and use a return in the inner menu to return to the outer menu.

Comment: And what are `option`, `function`?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure what your question is, but your code is missing 2 important things. First, you need break statements at the end of each case block, otherwise the program flow will continue on to the next case statement.
>
> Second, the inner menu doesn't ever escape the inner while(1) loop. This is a possible case for a goto use, although in practice it would better to refactor the code to split the top menu and inner menu into two functions, and use a return in the inner menu to return to the outer menu.

As said, you're code is missing various things. It would be awesome if you distribute the **entire code**, and additionally the **exact error message** with line.

> void value not ignored as it ought to be?...

...Is not that much of an explanation...

Also, are you sure you included iostream?

```
#include iostream
```

That said, you did not declare **any** of the variables used in the program.

You also missed a space in line 2 of your mainMenu() function.

Also, please tell us what you expected to happen.